# How to capture selected (Not copied) text from any application in android?

Tags: android

As said in the title is there a way by which I can capture selected (Not copied) text from any application in android?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView txtview;
String stringSelected = txtview.getText().toString;
int startIndex = txtview.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = txtview.getSelectionEnd();
stringSelected = stringSelected.subString(startIndex, endIndex);


if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
android.text.ClipboardManager clpbrd = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText(stringSelected);
} else {
android.content.ClipboardManager clpbrd = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", stringSelected);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but this requires the text to be copied. Is there any selected text event?